# Why the classpath in A does not compile?

Tags: java, classpath, package

I am learning classpaths and how to insert package files in a classpath, I am having a problem in understanding this example. Here it is :

Given the default classpath:
              /foo
And this directory structure:

```
 foo
  |
 test
   |
   xcom
    |--A.class
    |--B.java
```

And these two files:

```
package xcom;
public class A { }
package xcom;
public class B extends A { }
```

Which allows B.java to compile?

A. Set the current directory to xcom then invoke
javac -classpath . B.java

B. Set the current directory to test then invoke
javac -classpath . xcom/B.java

Only B compiles, my question is why doesn't A compile ?
if we set current directory to xcom ,then since A.class is present in xcom , A should also work fine , but it doesn't, why is it so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's looking for the package `xcom` as a subdirectory of `xcom`.

Set the `classpath` to `..`, and option A works.

Comment: first of all thank you for answering, and my doubt is that as there is  a dot(.) in option A , will the compiler not look in xcom , since it is the current directory now? I mean if it can see B.java it can also see A.class?

Comment: The compiler will only look in that directory for classes in the default package.